# How to read NFC Beam and tags?

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days now and I need help. I want to read HCE and beams with my app, independently they work fine, but when I want to put them together the onTagDiscovered is the one always getting called and never gets any info when it comes from beams.

I think is possible, but I'm new to this so probably I'm doing something crazy.

Here is the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {

    private var command: ByteArray? = null
    private lateinit var mNFCAdapter: NfcAdapter

    companion object {
        val TAG: String = com.solano.nfc.isodep.reader.MainActivity::class.java.name
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mNFCAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)

        command = Utils.hexStringToByteArray("00A4040007A220100247100100")
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume")

        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        val pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)

        val filters = arrayOfNulls<IntentFilter>(1)
        val techList =
            arrayOf<Array<String>>()

        // Filter for nfc tag discovery

        // Filter for nfc tag discovery
        filters[0] = IntentFilter()
        filters[0]!!.addAction(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)
        filters[0]!!.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        filters[0]!!.addDataType("application/vnd.com.example.myapp")

        if(::mNFCAdapter.isInitialized){
            val flags = NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A or NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_SKIP_NDEF_CHECK
            mNFCAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, this, flags, intent.extras)
            mNFCAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, techList)
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause")
        mNFCAdapter.disableReaderMode(this)
        mNFCAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        Log.d(TAG, "onNewIntent ${intent!!.action}")
        handleIntents(intent)
    }

    private fun handleIntents(intent: Intent?) {
        if (true) {
            val rawMessages = intent!!.getParcelableArrayExtra(
                NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES
            )
            val message =
                rawMessages!![0] as NdefMessage // only one message transferred
            tvMain.text = String(message.records[0].payload)
        } else tvMain.text = "Waiting for NDEF Message"
    }

    override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTagDiscovered")
        try{
            val nDef = Ndef.get(tag)
            val isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag)

            if (nDef != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "NDEF is supported")
            } else if (isoDep != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "ISO-Dep is supported")
                if(!isoDep.isConnected){
                    isoDep.connect()
                    val response = isoDep.transceive(command)
                    val status = Utils.getStatus(response!!)
                    if(status == "9000") {
                        Log.d(TAG, "OK\n${String(response)}")
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "WTF Status code: $status")
                    }
                    isoDep.close()
                }
            }

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, ex.message)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using both `enableReaderMode`  and `enableForegroundDispatch` as they are just different API's to do the same thing (read tags) BUT `enableReaderMode` Disables the deprecated Android Beam if available.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter#enableReaderMode(android.app.Activity,%20android.nfc.NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)

> In this mode the NFC controller will only act as an NFC tag reader/writer, thus disabling any peer-to-peer (Android Beam) and card-emulation modes of the NFC adapter on this device.

I would just use `enableForegroundDispatch`

Comment: Hmmm, that's what I'm doing wrong. But, I started doing this because I was trying to read an Emulated Card and I was getting anything from it.

Comment: Really reading HCE and Beam together is complicated AND you need to handle where Beam is not available in later version of Android as well. Going forward I would ignore Beam and focus just on HCE (Which `enableReaderMode` is easier because it disables Beam if available). It all depends on if you are also programming the other device.

Comment: Well, my interest on this just started when I tried to read an emulated card and later a tag. The HCE was working fine but the other one wasn't. And later I found a couple of apps capable of doing both. And I really want to understand how they are doing it. I have a ISO tag and I'm using an app that is using beam and another one that does HCE. The only thing I'm building is the reader to be honest

Comment: I just think it is a waste of effort trying to understand how they are doing both as Beam has been removed from Android 10 and above. There is a chance that one of the devices just won't have it available and that chance will only increase over time as more devices are Android 10 or above. There is no easy way really handle the scenario where the sending device is trying Beam but the receiver is not Beam capable, the sender will just see it as no device in range yet and keep waiting until one is in range.